# When Raising an MouseButtonEvent from a UserControl the MainWindow have no access to MouseButtonEventArgs

Tags: wpf, events, user-controls, event-bubbling

Still climbing up the steep WPF Mountain, and suffering.

I have defined a UserControl, and my MainWindow needs to retrieve the MouseButtonEventArgs coming from a control inside the UserControl (like the mouse e.GetPosition for instance)

In the UserControl code behind, I have done the Registrations and I Raise the bubbling event.

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent MyButtonDownEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("MyMouseButtonDown", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyUserControl));
    public event RoutedEventHandler MyButtonDown {
        add { AddHandler(MyButtonDownEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(MyButtonDownEvent, value); }
    }
    private void MyMouseButtonDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MyButtonDownEvent ));
    }
```

Now in my MainWindow I declare the UserControl like this:

```
<local:MyUserControl MouseDown="MyUserControl_MouseDown"/>
```

And this code behind

```
private void MyUserControl_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

And I receive the events from the UserControl, but the Args are RoutedEventArgs (which is normal) but I dont have access to the MouseButtonEventArgs that I need to get the mouse e.GetPosition.

What elegant solution would you suggest in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally got it (at least I hope):

If I write in the code behind:

```
        public event EventHandler<MouseButtonEventArgs> MyRightButtonDownHandler;
    public void MyRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        MyRightButtonDownHandler(sender, e);
    }
```

Then in the consumer (MainWindow) XAML:

```
<local:GlobalDb x:Name="globalDb"  MyRightButtonDownHandler="globalDb_MyRightButtonDownHandler"/>
```

And in the consumer code behind:

```
    private void globalDb_MyRightButtonDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("x= " + e.GetPosition(null).X + " y= " + e.GetPosition(null).Y);
    }
```

Please tell me if you have a better solution (By design policy - rules established where I work - all the event handling of my application MUST appear in the XAML).

Thanks again for your help,

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant, it's far more simple than using routed events, of course sometimes your events need to be routed though

Answer (score 1):

Why do you define your own `MouseDown` event while `UserControl` already has a normal MouseDown event?

Anyway, if you define an event to use a `RoutedEventHandler` it is hardly surprising that you'll end up being stuck with a `RoutedEventHandler`. You declared it like this:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent MyButtonDownEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("MyMouseButtonDown", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyUserControl));
```

Notice the bit where it says `typeof(RoutedEventHandler)`?

If i am not mistaken your code should look like this instead:

```
    public static readonly RoutedEvent MyButtonDownEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent
        ("MyButtonDown",
        RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(MouseButtonEventHandler),
        typeof(MyUserControl));

    public event MouseButtonEventHandler MyButtonDown
    {
        add { AddHandler(MyButtonDownEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(MyButtonDownEvent, value); }
    }
```

Example of how to propagate an existing MouseDown event to the custom event:

```
InitializeComponent();
this.MouseDown += (s, e) => {
    RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.ChangedButton)
                    { 
                        RoutedEvent = MyButtonDownEvent
                    });
};
```

Comment: Hello HB,Thank you for your effort

Comment: Hello HB, thank you for your help . To reply to your comment "Why do you define your own MouseDown event while UserControl already has a normal MouseDown event?". I did not find the way to do that using only XAML in the MainWindow to subscribe to the Event coming from the UserControl. I also tested your code and noticed that the XAML considers the type is mismatched. Any idea ?

Comment: No, i tried to fix it for some time but didn't work it out. If you don't mind not registering it as a RoutedEvent there should be no problem (you'd need to get rid of the setter and getter for the event too)

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I found 3 things: a) Your declaration for registering the event was RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(MouseButtonEventArgs),typeof(MyUserControl)); I think it should be typeof(MouseButtonEventHandler). Am I right ? 2) After that I found that the XAML compiler was not complaining when the event consumer code behind changes the RoutedEventArgs to MouseButtonEventArgs e 3) It seems that RaiseEvent(e) does nothing but RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MyButtonDownEvent)) give an exception trying to convert RoutedEvent to MouseButtonEvent. Any ideas ?

Comment: "RoutedEvent there should be no problem (you'd need to get rid of the setter and getter for the event too)". Could you please give me a code snippet based on what u wrote yesterday, then I will leave you alone :)

Comment: Found a solution, see my answer above.